# DHCP on multiple ranges?

Tags: dhcp

I would like to ask how can I configure a dhcp to work from 192.168.0.2 - 192.168.255.255 for example. Is this a software or hardware tweak? Also do I need a special server/router/software? Thank you in advance.

Comment: Welcome to NE, we hope you will both contribute to and learn from this community. Unfortunately, it is not clear what you are asking. Please [edit] your question and it will automatically start a reopen vote. You may find our [Question Checklist](http://meta.networkengineering.stackexchange.com/q/292/33) helpful to improve your question.

Comment: If you need mutliple ranges within a subnet and use ISC DHCP (or alike), [this should answer your question](https://serverfault.com/a/289835/47300). There are different implementations out there, [Wikipedia names a few (OSS only)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_DHCP_server_software) but there are several commercial implementations (i.e. [Microsoft](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc732584(v=ws.11).aspx) or [cisco](https://www.cisco.com/c/en/us/td/docs/ios-xml/ios/ipaddr_dhcp/configuration/12-4t/dhcp-12-4t-book/config-dhcp-server.html)) as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just configure your DHCP server with scope 192.168.0.2 - 192.168.255.254 and subnet mask 255.255.0.0. Here's an example how to do it with Microsoft DHCP server:

[image: DHCP scope on MS server]

.255.255 is the broadcast address, so that cannot be assigned to a device.

Comment: That's what I needed, is this software/hardware specific? Is it applyable to routers? Tnx!

Comment: No, it's not specific to Windows DHCP server, that was only used as an example. You should be able to do this with any DHCP service.

Comment: If you  need to know whether this is applicable to devices, you need to name the device. For example my home DSL router can't do /16 networks at all.

Answer (score -3):

I do not think that would be possible. Remember that is a class C address range which defaults to a 255.255.255.0 subnet mask. 
For 192.168.0.2 the end would be 192.168.0.254. So you would most likely define different ranges I think.

192.168.0.2 to 192.168.0.254
192.168.1.1 to 192.168.1.254 and so on

Comment: I think @Arimo's answer is more like what you need.

Comment: Classful addressing really isn't a thing anymore.